# Is it possible to 'virtualize' an USB device? (Keyboard in particular)

Tags: usb, keyboard, virtual-machine, vmware

*Disclaimer: The title is really bad, but I found no good way of summarizing this, sorry.*

I have seen it's possible to virtually mount a CD-drive by using programs like WinCDEmu. So I was wondering if you could virtually create an USB-device. My goal would be to create a virtual Keyboard, which then I could use in a Virtual Machine I am running on VMWare.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What would you expect this virtual keyboard to do?

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking about virtualization the wrong way.  Usually, USB devices are just "passed-through" to the VM (virtual machine).  You don't need to virtualize your keyboard or mouse as the system-level commands they send over the USB interface are passed directly to the driver in VMware.

Other things like disk drives, as you pointed out, can be virtualized.  However, they can sometimes operate in "pass-through" mode as well sometimes.  More often than not, though, you won't have to virtualize things like a keyboard and mouse.  Hope that helps!